visionOS resize control behavior can't be coordinated
I opened a window using the windowgroup in visionOS. The only thing I wanted is to keep the window's width and height ratio to a constant. But the resize controls can scale really wild. How can I achieve this? Oh by the way I put a RealityView inside the ContentView，did this make it worse？
I tried the following:
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else { return }
   window.frame.size = CGSize(width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight) 

the windowWidth and windowHeight are got from the geometryReader wrapped around contentView.
but the effect is very weird, and cannot responding to further instructions.

problem solved, the solution is in UIWindowScene. My bad I didn't explain the question straight. The Geometry preference can be set to .uniform, then the whole window can be resized according  to the view inside.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
